# Extension modules VS web-extension when customizing Alfresco Share

Tags: customization, share, alfresco

Well I'm working since some months ago with Alfresco 4.2b, mainly with Share. I'm preforming some customization works and my colleagues and myself are always wondering about the subject of this post.

We know extension modules is a relatively new feature which is available since the first release of Alfresco 4 but we don't know which way should the developments performed take in terms of the extension mechanism used. We are putting all our efforts on using the extension module mechanism rather than using the web-extension directory. We are doing that because we understand that probably the it is more versatile, maintainable and scalable and who knows, perhaps the use of the web-extension directory could be deprecated in further releases. We are also aware that at the moment you cannot do "everything" with extension modules.

So according to that, I would like to know about pros and cons of both mechanisms based on other developers experience, as well as whether we are doing right with our extension philosophy. At the same time, I would like to find a reasonable answer to the next questions:

1. Are we doing right prioritizing and "sacrifice" our time trying to perform customization with extension modules? Is it worth?
2. Could be deprecated the web-extension directory as a customization mechanism in further releases?
3. Is the extension modules feature going to be improved?
4. (Roughly) known limitations of  extension modules? Mainly the question could be, when should be used one extension mechanism or the other?

I'm looking forward to hear your opinions. It would be strongly appreciated opinions based on your real experience and as honest as possible.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Actually both are not exclusive.

I'm using myself for instance the extension mechanism to define new components which webscripts are defined in the web-extension folder.

In fact the extension module itself can be located in the web-extension folder under alfresco/web-extension/site-data/extensions/...

For me using the extension modules is a way to logically package (because of the deployment process of modules) your customization. That's the main advantage because it can be configured through evaluators if you want the customization to be available only in particular conditions.

Comment: I know both are not exclusive, actually I'm using web-extension directory for one customization which I think is not possible to do as extension module. What I would like to have as an answer, is a comparative describing use cases if possible. Useful answer anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The two main problems with the `web-extension` route is that you will end up duplicating core code in your customisation, and that if multiple extensions try to extend the same component, one must win.

Extensibility modules may be a little bit more work but you will more than get that back in terms of a much reduced maintenance burden, and in troubleshooting problems when multiple add-ons clash with each other.

From 4.2 onwards you should not need to override web script components - in Share at least. You should always use an extensibility module.